# "Tell me which is your favourite one" or "Tell me which your favourite one is"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, phrase-requests

in a situation where I'm showing three pictures to someone, what is grammatically correct to say (and with what difference in meaning)?

**Tell me which is your favourite one.**
or
**Tell me which your favourite one is.**

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I think you should also consider adding tell me which one is your favorite

Comment: Thank you.
And what about the grammatical question I asked above?

Comment: Please, any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on whether the question "which one is your favorite?" is in quotes. If the question is not quoted, it should be:

> Tell me which your favourite one is.

If the question is quoted, then it should be:

> Tell me, "which one is your favorite?".